# Any arguments for [command-line-arguments]?

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

[command-line-arguments](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/command-line-arguments) is a classic meta-tag. Any arguments for keeping it?

Comment: We have [command-line].  But what if the question is specifically about just the arguments?  For example, whether they're uppercase or lowercase.  Maybe we should go the other direction and have a tag [command-line-argument-capitalization].  And in case anyone wants to discuss that tag on Meta, we should have one here [command-line-argument-capitalization-tag].  Lest anyone think this is serious,  :-)

Comment: a command-line-arguments tag is to superuser what a programming tag would be to stackoverflow. to be consistent, either command-line-arguments should be burninated, or a programming tag should be added to stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 3):

Any question with a command line arguement tag *ought* to have a command line tag, unless it shouldn't. We could merge the tags, then pick off the questions where the tag dosen't belong as we go along

Answer (score 2):

We should go oldschool, dinobot style on this tag, and delete it from each post.

[image]